# How many even numbers can you form greater than $5000$ from the digits $1$ to $7$ inclusive, if no repetition is allowed?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many even numbers can you form greater than $5000$ from the digits $1$ to $7$ inclusive, if no repetition is allowed?

*My Attempted Solution*

$n = 3 \times 6 \times 5 \times 3 = 270$

My reasoning, for the first digit, only $5, 6, 7$ can be chosen, thus leading to $3$ possible choice, and since no repitition is allowed it follows that there can only be $6$ subsequent choices for the second digits and $5$ for the third. Finally only $2, 4, 6$ can be chosen for the fourth digits, leading to $3$ possible choice for the fourth digit.

---

Is my solution correct? If not, where is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: $1235764$ is an even number which is greater than $5000$ made from the digits $1$ to $7$ inclusive without repetition. Are you counting that one as well?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a flaw in your logic.  There's no way of knowing how many even digits you have for the last digit.

I would probably break this problem into two cases.  The first is that the first digit is a $6$.  I'd then consider what the last digit could be since it's the only other digit that has restrictions.  Then the remaining digits can be chosen from whatever's left over.

Upon seeing Chas Brown's comment bringing up that the problem has apparently not forbidden numbers with five or more digits, I decided I should address those cases as well.  The simplest method adds another three cases: one for five-digit, six-digit, and seven-digit numbers.  These three cases should be simpler since the thousands digit no longer matters.  There are three ways to choose the final digit while each remaining digit can be anything that hasn't already been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE IGNORE - I misread question as 4 digit numbers

I agree with Mike, this should be broken up into two case: starting with 6 and starting with 5/7.

Then, I believe the key is to next select the last digit (needs to be even) to avoid having to break into more cases.  Then the 2nd and 3rd digits.

starting with 6:    1 * 2 * 5 * 4 = 40

starting with 5/7:  2 * 3 * 5 * 4 = 120

For a total of 160.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the number of $7$-digit even numbers, plus the number of $6$-digit even numbers, plus the number of $5$-digit even numbers, plus the number of $4$-digit even numbers that start with $7$, $6$, or $5$; all of which obey the 'digits in 1-7 with no repetition' constraint.

The easier ones are the first cases; let $(x)_n$ be the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), i.e:
$$(x)_n = x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)$$

Then, if we let $f(n)$ be the number of even numbers with digits in 1-7 without repetition, then

$$f(n) = 3 \cdot (6)_{n-1}$$

because we choose the rightmost digit to be one of $2, 4,$ or $6$; and then starting from the left, choose from the remaining $6$ digits, then $5$ digits, etc.

So

$$f(7) = 3 \cdot (6)_6 = 3 \cdot 6! = 3 \cdot 720 = 2160$$
$$f(6) = 3 \cdot (6)_5 = 3 \cdot (6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2) = 3 \cdot 720 = 2160$$
$$f(5) = 3 \cdot (6)_4 = 3 \cdot (6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3) = 3 \cdot 360 = 1080$$

For the $4$ digit numbers, when they start with $7$, we choose the rightmost digit to be one of $2, 4,$ or $6$, and then choose the third digit from the $5$ remaining digits and then the second digit from the $4$ remaining digits; giving us $3 \cdot (5)_2 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 60$. And the same is true for the $4$ digit numbers that start with $5$.

For the $4$ digit numbers, when they start with $6$, the logic is the same, but now we only have two even numbers to choose from for the rightmost digit: $2$ or $4$. So we get $2 \cdot (5)_2 = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 40$

So finally (!), we get

$$f(7) + f(6) + f(5) + 3 \cdot (5)_2 + 2 \cdot (5)_2 + 3 \cdot (5)_2$$
$$ = 720 + 720 + 1080 + 60 + 40+ 60$$
$$ = 2680$$

Answer (score 0):

Such numbers can have $n=4$, $5$, $6$, or $7$ decimal places. If $n\geq5$ start writing the number with the last decimal place, which is one of $\{2,4,6\}$. Proceeding to the left, we first have $6$ possibilities, then $5$, etc., to choose from for the nextleft digit. It follows that there are
$$3\cdot6\cdot 5\cdot4\cdot 3\cdot(1+2+2\cdot 1)=5400$$
such numbers with $n\geq5$.

If $n=4$ then we can have one of $\{5,7\}$ at first place and one of $\{2,4,6\}$ at last place, or $6$ at first place and one of $\{2,4\}$ at last place. In both cases there are  $5\cdot 4=20$ choices left for the digits in between. It follows that there are $(2\cdot 3+1\cdot 2)\cdot 20=160$ four digit numbers fulfilling the conditions.

The total count of admissible numbers therefore is $5560$.